# What is the shortcut path to the existing plugins folder using file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, wordpress

My code is inside a plugin's init function and I'm trying to file_get_contents() on a file inside my plugin folder..

I'm using...

```
file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myfile.html');
```

Not sure why can't I just use...

```
file_get_contents('myfile.html');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is php file where you call file_get_contents called directly or required from another script?
Path to files calculated from file, which run directly. 
For example: in index.php my be required 'plugins/i/plagin78.php
If in plugin78.php you called file_get_contents('myfile.html') then myfile.html should be placed in same category as index.php, not plugin78.php

Answer (score 0):

`myfile` or `myfile.html?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file_get_contents('./myfile.html');
```

Comment: I thought that, but its still giving me issues. I believe its because the file is being loaded into plugins.php from another directory, which becomes the current relative path.

Answer (score 0):

> you can ***file*** function  also, to read
>   the specific file.

Refer following link

[link text](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: Thanks, my ? is not so much about the method, but rather about the apparent unique relationship of the path when code is being executed inside a plugin's init function in wordpress.